# get health checks automatically using API calls in Foundry Slate

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

Is there a way to get health checks automatically using API calls and show it in Foundry Slate application. I am trying to get the available data sets info such as health checks and show them in the dashboard automatically using API calls based on RID as a param or any other way

Answer (score 2):

Within slate, if you open `queries` you should have an endpoint to hit the data health service api. Open the source dropdown and search for `data-health SERVICE API` (blue arrow on the image).

Afterwards a new dropdown should show up with the available services that you can query data health with (green arrow). Depending on your stack it is also possible that this is a `JSON API` instead of a `SERVICE API`, in that case it can look slightly different from the screenshot.

[image]